# Bibliography details (volume, page numbers) not printed

Tags: bibliographies

In all bibliography styles I found online, volume and page numbers are printed. However, whenever I try this does not happen, I only get authors, title, journal and year for articles, and only title, publisher and year in books.

I use bibtex:

```
\bibliographystyle{plain}
\bibliography{myreferences}
```

What am I doing wrong? I am probably overlooking something really basic.

EDIT: example bib-entry:

```
@Article{Pope00,
author = {Pope, R.J. and Millington, A.C.},
title = {Unravelling the patterns of alluvial fan development using mineral magnetic analysis: examples from the {S}parta basin, {L}akonia, southern {G}reece},
journal = {Earth surface processes and landforms},
year = {2000},
OPTvolume = {25},
OPTpages = {601-615},
}
```

Comment: Can you add an example of a bib entry in `myreferences.bib` that doesn't print correctly?

Comment: Done it. I do not have the same information for all references, but most of them look like this.

Comment: Remove OPT; Emacs adds it so that unfilled optional fields are ignored; in order that `plain.bst` understands them they must be called `volume` and `pages`.

Comment: Thanks for your comment. The thing is, I've tried that. I reran my compiler a couple of times (I am using TexMakerX) but still no details...

Comment: Did you run BibTeX again?

Comment: Yes, several times too.

Comment: I don't know why, but after running the compiler and bibtex a couple of times more it works. I am now going to try and add `volume' and p. for the pages. Thank you!

Answer (score 7, accepted):

A tradition that I believe was inaugurated by the BibTeX mode of Emacs, to which TeXStudio (formerly TeXMakerX) adheres, is that optional fields in a bibliographic entry are prefixed by `OPT`. So when you ask for a new `@article` entry, you get something like

```
@Article{,
  author = {},
  title = {},
  journal = {},
  year = {},
  OPTkey = {},
  OPTvolume = {},
  OPTnumber = {},
  OPTpages = {},
  OPTmonth = {},
  OPTnote = {},
  OPTannote = {}
}
```

(maybe with bullets to stand for the field contents). This is because some of the fields are *optional* and some are ignored by the standard styles, but are useful anyway. The only mandatory fields for an article are `author`, `title`, `journal` and `year`.

Since the rule of BibTeX is to ignore unknown fields, those prefixed with `OPT` will be ignored whether filled or empty. But if you fill them you have also to remove the `OPT` prefix. So, in your case, the entry should look like

```
@Article{Pope00,
  author = {Pope, R.J. and Millington, A.C.},
  title = {Unravelling the patterns of alluvial fan development using mineral magnetic
           analysis: examples from the {Sparta} basin, {Lakonia}, southern {Greece}},
  journal = {Earth surface processes and landforms},
  year = {2000},
  volume = {25},
  pages = {601-615},
}
```

Note also that, contrary to what's found in many guides, it's preferable to brace the entire word we want to maintain the capitalization of, so that kerning will be applied between all the letters.